# Ant delete and display a set for files

Tags: ant

I am trying to delete a bunch of files after a certain pattern. I am successful at this, but I want to also display the files which are delete. All my attempts to nest echo are met with either a deprecate message or with a not supported.

Were is my simple code:

```
<target name="foo">
  <delete>
     <fileset dir="my_path">
        <filename regex="\w+(\.log|_log\.txt)"/>
        <echo message="%filename" />
     </fileset>
  </delete> 

</target>
```

The echo in there is met with an error: **fileset doesn't support the nested "echo" element.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [delete task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) has a verbose flag.

## Example

```
build:
   [delete] Deleting /../build/file1.txt
   [delete] Deleting /../build/file2.txt
   [delete] Deleting /../build/file3.txt
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="build"/>
    <echo file="build/file1.txt" message="hello world"/>
    <echo file="build/file2.txt" message="hello world"/>
    <echo file="build/file3.txt" message="hello world"/>

    <delete verbose="true">
      <fileset dir="build" includes="*.txt"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. I know I looked over the attributes of the delete, but somehow I missed it. Thanks again.